# LinearProgressIndicator - Change Size of the indicator Android

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress

Is there any option to change the indicator width. We have api to change colour of the indicator. Similarly any api available to change size of indicator in indeterminate mode

```
<com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
        android:id="@+id/connect_progress_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_indeterminate_drawable"
        android:progress="50"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

[wanted to achieve the loader like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikRvC.png)

Comment: I went through all the docs but sadly did not find any attribute of LinearProgressIndicator that manipulates the indicator width,

Comment: Thanks. I am going for some custom approach not using progress bar